# Importing multiple CSV to a single Excel with CSV file name into a new column

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am trying to import multiple .csv files to a single excel sheet. I would like the .csv file names to be a separate column during the import process in every row.

My code below:

```
Sub Combinecsvs()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim WbResult As Workbook

FolderPath = ""
If FolderPath Like "*[!\/]" Then
    FolderPath = FolderPath & "/"
End If

FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.csv")
Set WbResult = ActiveWorkbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While FileName <> vbNullString
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FolderName & FileName)
    WB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy WB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(WbResult.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Offset(1).Resize(1)
    WB.Close False
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You've not explained any problem you're having with your code, or asked any sort of question at all. You've just told us what you want to do. Are you asking for permission to do it?

Comment: You may also consider to use Power Query to read csv files in a directory as a data source.

Answer (score 1):

Filename added in Column A for every row imported.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Combinecsvs()

    Dim WbResult As Workbook, rngCSV As Range, rng As Range
    Dim wbCSV As Workbook, folderpath As String
    Dim FileName As String, n As Long
    
    folderpath = "C:\temp\so\csv"
    If folderpath Like "*[!\/]" Then
        folderpath = folderpath & "/"
    End If
    
    FileName = Dir(folderpath & "*.csv")
    Set WbResult = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With WbResult.Sheets(1)
        Do While FileName <> vbNullString
            ' source
            Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(folderpath & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
            Set rngCSV = wbCSV.Sheets(1).UsedRange
            
            ' target
            Set rng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            rngCSV.Copy rng.Offset(, 1)
            rng.Resize(rngCSV.Rows.Count) = FileName
            wbCSV.Close False
            n = n + 1
            
            FileName = Dir()
        Loop
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox n & " csv files imported", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- The CSV file name is located in column A.
- Imported data starts from column B.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Combinecsvs()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim WbResult As Workbook
    Dim WB As Workbook
    FolderPath = "D:\Temp\csv"
    If FolderPath Like "*[!\/]" Then
        FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
    End If
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.csv")
    Set WbResult = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim c As Range
    Do While FileName <> vbNullString
        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        With WbResult.ActiveSheet
            If Len(.Cells(1, 1)) = 0 Then
                Set c = .Cells(1, 1)
            Else
                Set c = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
            c.Value = FileName
            Set c = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
            WB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy c
        End With
        WB.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

[image]

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

---

*Update:*

> Question: Can i please check if i want to allow the user to choose the folder where to import the csv files how can i do in this same code?

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Combinecsvs()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim WbResult As Workbook
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim dialog As FileDialog
    Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With dialog
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
            MsgBox "You cancelled the operation."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.csv")
    Set WbResult = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim c As Range
    Do While FileName <> vbNullString
        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        With WbResult.ActiveSheet
            If Len(.Cells(1, 1)) = 0 Then
                Set c = .Cells(1, 1)
            Else
                Set c = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
            c.Value = FileName
            Set c = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
            WB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy c
        End With
        WB.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, This worked perfectly. Can i please check if i want to allow the user to choose the folder where to import the csv files how can i do in this same code?

Comment: Sure, see the updated code.